# List of What Policies Require Background Refresh, Which Require Reboot

Tags: windows, group-policy

Yes, I know the obvious ones.  I am very specifically looking for **any doc by Microsoft/MSDN** that indicates which policies in Group Policy specifically require reboot and which do not. I love trial and error as much as the next guy, but I would love to have a document like this handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked (googled "group policy reboot site:microsoft.com"), but to be frank, I don't think such a document exists. Even on the Microsoft forums, the Microsoft staff point you to this link: http://www.petri.co.il/working_with_group_policy.htm

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverGP/thread/1aed8cf6-5298-4412-9a88-77f1dd387284 (note, this was a thread from this month even).

Comment: OK, I'll give up and reward you for the effort.